# Select Widget Model Form with static content from a list in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have a simple model as follows:

```
games = ['soccer', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'cricket', 'basketball']
db.define_table('Sportsmen',
                Field('gamer', db.auth_user),
                Field('games', length=20),
                Field('experience', 'integer', default=0))
```

All i want to do is populate the list of games in a dropdown menu via a sql form. I saw the selectwidget, but the examples were slightly complicated(they wwere putting all the options in a database and rendering that db into a dropdown, for my case only a small list is suffice) for this small purpose. The analogous django functionality is found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a requires argument to create that dropdown.

```
games_set = set('soccer', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'cricket', 'basketball')
db.define_table('Sportsmen',
            Field('gamer', db.auth_user),
            Field('games', length=20, 
                requires=IS_IN_SET(games_set))),
            Field('experience', 'integer', default=0))
```

This will give you a dropdown in the form with only the items from the set.

Answer (score 2):

If each gamer can have multiple games and you want to store them as a list in a single field, you can use a [list:string](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Many-to-many,-list%3A%3Ctype%3E%2C-and-contains) field type and add `multiple=True` to the [`IS_IN_SET()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#Validators) validator.

```
Field('games', 'list:string', requires=IS_IN_SET(games_set, multiple=True))
```